# How to get a bash parameter substitution to work properly?

Tags: regex, bash, substitution

I have a bash variable like

```
var=root@283.45.67.89:/root/test
```

and want to access the different parts (user, host, path, in which the user is optional). I tried:

```
path=${var#*:*}
user=${var%*@*}
host=${{var#*@*}%*:*}
```

While the expressions for `PATH` and `user` work as expected (i.e. `USER` has string `root` and `path` has string `/root/test`), the expression for getting `host` (i.e. the part between the `@` sign and the `:` sign) gives a `bad substitution` error. Is there a simple/elegant way to fix this expression in a single line, in order to extract the 'middle' part of the original variable?

Additional information: It also must work when no user is given, i.e. in the following case without a user (and without a '@' sign), the variable `user` must be empty, but the other variables must be filled accordingly:

```
var=283.45.67.89:/root/test
```

I expect the following result

```
path=/root/test
host=283.45.67.89
user=
```

Answer (score 3):

Use lowercase variable names. $PATH and $USER are special.

To parse the string, you can use a regular expression:

```
[[ $var =~ (.*)@(.*):(.*) ]]
user=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} 
host=${BASH_REMATCH[2]} 
path=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
```

**Update:**
For a possibly missing user, you can change it to

```
[[ @$var =~ (.*)@(.*):(.*) ]]
user=${BASH_REMATCH[1]#@}
```

Comment: Thanks for noting out using lowercase variables. Also, I forgot to mention that the substitution must work if no user is specified...

Comment: @chepner: The updated version already works for both the cases (user present - user not present). I do not see a reason of your edit.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary variable (tmp) may amend the problem with bad substitution error, and this work both with and without user:

```
path=${var#*:}      # Get path
tmp=${var%:*}       # Get all before ":"
host=${tmp#*@}      # Get host by removing any user and "@"
tmp=${tmp%${host}}  # Get any user and "@" by prevoving host
user=${tmp%@}       # Remove any "@" from user
```